A zonejs dependency error in package.json
I experienced this bug while running npm install I found out the error was caused in a few PR's that my dependency upgrade tool Snyk had created.

https://github.com/oc-2/2.0-Website-Breaker/pull/22
https://github.com/oc-2/2.0-Website-Breaker/pull/21
https://github.com/oc-2/2.0-Website-Breaker/pull/20
https://github.com/oc-2/2.0-Website-Breaker/pull/19
https://github.com/oc-2/2.0-Website-Breaker/pull/18

This is what I see when running npm install:
npm error code ERESOLVE

npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.11
npm error Found: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.12
npm error node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm error   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.11
npm error node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm error   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^18.2.11" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@18.2.11
npm error node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm error   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.11
npm error   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm error     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^18.2.11" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-11-12T23_36_23_968Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.8.1 -> 10.9.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.0
npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.9.0
npm notice
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-11-12T23_36_23_968Z-debug-0.log

I am expecting not to see npm errors when running npm commands. This is what I see when running npm install:
npm error code ERESOLVE

npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.11
npm error Found: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.12
npm error node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm error   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.11
npm error node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm error   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^18.2.11" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@18.2.11
npm error node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm error   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.11
npm error   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm error     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^18.2.11" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-11-12T23_36_23_968Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.8.1 -> 10.9.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.0
npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.9.0
npm notice
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-11-12T23_36_23_968Z-debug-0.log


please share package.json

You need to make sure that your Angular dependencies have the same major version. Those automatically created PRs are wrong. Follow the update guide to update your project from Angular 13 to Angular 18.

Thanks @JSONDerulo, upgrading from Angular 13 to Angular 18 was just the trick!
